# How to check secret word from md5 hash

Tags: md5

I am getting md5 hash in response for a service, I would to check my secret key is present in the md5 hash. I need some idea on how to decode the md5 hash key to check my word. Thanks.

Comment: A MD5 hash cannot be decoded, spendfive minutes reading about how it works before asking how to do something

Answer (score 2):

Aside from hashing what you think the MD5 your getting back and comparing there is no real way to decrypt a hash like MD5.

MD5 is a [one-way hashing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function). There is no way to decode them. The only way to remotely figure out what an MD5 hash represents is by using [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) and even then your limited by a string length up to 64 characters or so, to dictionary words, numbers and any related combinations.

Simple and sure answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the way to approach this would be to apply the same hashing algorithm to your known secret word, then compare the result to the hash you received from the service. By design it is not possible to decrypt an MD5 hash

Answer (score 0):

You can't decode the md5 hash.

An idea for understand how normally works: You need to store the md5 in a BD for example. After, you take the string entered by a user, for example, convert to md5 and then, compare the two strings.

Answer (score 0):

I am totally Agree With Above Answers. And for example if u wanna get any user with one's password , then u need to use like

```
password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'
```

in Your Select query when user is being checked due login time.... 
I think u need like this...
u cant match posted password with Db if u wont use .md5 before it..